# Subscribing with SwitchMap in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angular5

I'm trying to show a page with all the products and a section with categories, but only the categories is rendering.

I don't see the products on the page.

The console shows the error:

```
main.653279d3d097093b55e7.js:1 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 't'
```

My code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from '../product.service';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { map, switchMap, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { CategoryService } from '../category.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Product } from '../models/product';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.css']
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  products: any = {};
  productsRef: AngularFireList<any>;
  filteredProducts;
  categories: Observable<any>;
  categoriesRef: AngularFireList<any>;
  category;

  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute, private productService: ProductService, private categoryService: CategoryService) {

    this.productsRef = productService.getAll();

    this.products = this.productsRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes =>
        changes.map(c => ({key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
      )).switchMap (products => {
        this.products = products;
        return route.queryParamMap;
      }).subscribe (params => {
        this.category = params.get('category');
        this.filteredProducts = (this.category) ?
          this.products.filter(p => p.category === this.category) : this.products;
      });

    this.categoriesRef = this.categoryService.getAll();

    this.categories = this.categoriesRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(changes =>
          changes.map(c => ({key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
        )
      );
```

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Show us the code for `pipe` that you are using to display data

Comment: getAll() {
    return this.db.list('/products');
  }

Answer (score 0):

You should use `pipe()`

```
 this.products = this.productsRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes =>
        changes.map(c => ({key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
      ),
switchMap (products => {
        this.products = products;
        return route.queryParamMap;
      })
).subscribe (params => {
        this.category = params.get('category');
        this.filteredProducts = (this.category) ?
          this.products.filter(p => p.category === this.category) : this.products;
      });
```

Comment: Your answer is fine but as we can see author already use ``pipe(...)`` but not in all cases. Since ``switchMap`` is out of ``pipe`` method scope and it's used in old way(chaining function operators by dot) I would add that all of this should be inside ``pipe(...)``.

Comment: Buczkowski, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

`switchMap` signature expects that this function shall return `Observable<any>`:

`public switchMap(project: function(value: T, ?index: number): ObservableInput, resultSelector: function(outerValue: T, innerValue: I, outerIndex: number, innerIndex: number): any): Observable`

While you are returning `route.queryParamMap` which is not an `ObservableInput` type. Try to replace this line:

```
return route.queryParamMap;
```

with this:

```
return Observable.from(route.queryParamMap);
```

### Edit

Because my first answer was not valid due to my mistake I tried to re-write your strem to one that does not use `pipe` and uses `switchMap` at the beginning of it in order to prevent from re-querying incomplete strem.

```
this.products = this.productsRef.snapshotChanges()
.switchMap((products: AngularFireAction<DatabaseSnapshot>[]) => {
    return Observable.of(products); // Just re-emit things to guard re-query interruption
})
.map((snap: AngularFireAction<DatabaseSnapshot>[]) => { /* Do data manipulation */
  let mappedProducts = snap.map((s: AngularFireAction<DatabaseSnapshot>) => {
    return {key: s.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }
  })
  return mappedProducts;
})
.do((mappedProducts: any) => { /* Side effects */
  this.products = mappedProducts;
})
.concatMap(mappedProducts => {
  return route.queryParamMap;
})
.subscribe (params => {
  this.category = params.get('category');
  this.filteredProducts = (this.category) ?
    this.products.filter(p => p.category === this.category) : this.products;
});
```

Comment: Error "property 'get' does not exist on type {}.   line with .  this.category = params.get('category').   The word "get" is underlined

Comment: @Vini Pineda I'm terribly sorry, according to angular docs queryParamMap alredy is an observable of following type: `Observable<ParamMap>`. When you apply mi "fix" your code will work with nested observables, (`Observable<Observable<ParamMap>>`) which is something you totally don't wont. I'm sorry for my mistake, I didn't check the docs.